# Mobile apps as alternative to paper boarding pass

Tags: airports, mobile-apps

I print my boarding pass in advance before arriving at the airport. They check it during check-in and during boarding. However, I've seen some people using their mobile devices to present the boarding pass instead of a paper copy.

First, is that acceptable in all the airports?

Secondly, which app do they normally use?

Comment: 2: The airline's own app. 1: If the airline and airport support it (and if not the app won't offer it)

Comment: @Gagravarr my Ryanair profile in my app does have the boarding passes, but how can I know if both Lisbon and Porto's airports support Rayanir's app?

Comment: On the BA App at least, it says something like "mobile boarding pass unavailable" instead of "download boarding pass" if you're departing from an airport that doesn't support it. The App should know

Comment: @WilliamKinaan, the [Ryanair website](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview#7-1) tells us mobile boarding passes are available from all airports except Agadir, Essaouira,  Fez,  Nador,  Oujda, Marrakesh, Rabat, Tangier, Zaragoza, Alghero, Kefalonia, Volos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very airline specific.

- in most cases (of airlines supporting it), you have to use the airline's own app
- some airlines support sending you a mobile-optimised version of your boarding pass by e-mail or MMS
- other airlines will allow adding the boarding pass to the iOS "wallet" (previously known as Passbook), either from their own app, from their mobile website, or from an e-mail or text message. Not sure if there is an Android equivalent.
- [if the airline and airport allows it you can scan the paper boarding pass with a special app and make your own mobile boarding pass.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/152485/18374)

This is indeed not always possible in all airports and/or for all flights. The check-in process should prevent you from choosing mobile boarding pass for those airports that don't support it.

Comment: Another mechanism: they send a URL by e-mail or text message.  When you open the URL in your web browser, it displays the boarding pass.

Comment: I disagree with the *'in most cases you have to use the airline's own app'* - all airlines that I ever used support Apple wallet (delta, american, southwest, united, us, lufthansa, ba, berlin air, austrian, swiss air, indigo) - so who doesn't?

Comment: Do all of those support it without the app installed? I have to admit I don't usually use the mobile check-in option (always afraid I'll run out of battery at the wrong time) but I don't remember seeing the option to get the boarding pass into Wallet without going through the app in most of them. Did I miss it?

Comment: I am checking, it sounds like Rayanir doesn't support Apple Wallet

Comment: In my experience, you generally use the airline's own app and then add the pass from there into Apple Wallet. Sometimes you can check-in on the website, get the pass emailed to you, and add it to Apple Wallet that way, but some airlines don't offer that option if you check-in from the web insstead of their app.